# Mapping function with two arguments

Tags: python

```
def mod(x,y):
    return x%y

def prime(n):
    if n ==1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return list(map(mod, (range(1,(n)^.5,n)))
```

I am trying to check and see if 'n' in the prime function is a prime number.  The issue is with the else result of the function.  Without the list function I receive 'map object at 0x1020777f0' but after adding the list function I get "mod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'".  I'm wondering if there is anyway to receive a list with all the individual elements modulo'ed (not sure how to say that) by the entered 'n' value.  Lastly, to my knowledge list comprehension would work well but I have been instructed to not use that nor any loops.

Comment: Looks a bit complicated. Why not generator expressions and the `any` function instead of list?

Comment: Why do you have a `,`  after the word `mod` in the last line of your function?

Comment: @AMACB the first argument to `map` is the name of a function to call on each element of the list, and he's trying to call `mod`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return list(map(lambda divisor:mod(n,divisor), range(1,int((n)^.5)) ))
```

this is not a very efficient way to check for primes ... you should really look into a sieve function ;)